# LD_LIBRARY_PATH : how to find a shared object

Tags: linux

I have a shared object ( libxyz.so ). Given LD_LIBRARY_PATH, how can find the exact location of this shared object? If i had a binary that depends on this lib, i would have used ldd on that.

Here is the reason why i ask:
I have a cgi script which works when using LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to say VALUE1. It does not work when the path is set to VALUE2. I would like to find the exact location of the library as specified by the path in VALUE1 ( Note that VALUE1 has almost 20+ different locations )

Platform: Linux

Answer (score 13):

Put this in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=:

for p in ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}; do
    if [ -e ${p}/libxyz.so ]; then
        echo ${p}
    fi
done
```

and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was just wondering if there is an existing linux tool to this. Also, i noticed some files within the lib folders which have path names to other lib folders - so this also needs to recursively look at those directories

Comment: oh btw, this does not work without first splitting the path using : delimiter

Comment: @CuriousDawg - did you try the example exactly as I wrote it?  `IFS=:` tells bash to treat : as the delimiter (or field separator in bash parlance).

Comment: I've pasted a modified version of this on PasteBin as [ldfind](http://pastebin.com/PPLFXaEj). For those who are curious, you can see this in the `bash` man page. See it online [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), and search for "Internal Field Separator".

Answer (score 5):

You can also use ldd.  To do this, you would:

1. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the value when it works (i.e. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=VALUE1`)
2. Run `ldd /path/to/prog | grep libxyz.so`

Comment: Yes i can do that, but this is a cgi script and ldd does not work on scripts

Comment: @CuriousDawg - if it's a script, run `ldd` on the interpreter (i.e. the program after `#!`)

Answer (score 0):

put a sleep(30); in your cgi, launch it from a browser, then look into /proc/$(pidof mycgi)/maps for actual libs used by your program.