# Lua ffi.load fails to find library without absolute path

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

Lua's `ffi.load("library")` results in a `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error.

As a temporary solution I can provide the absolute or relative path to the library.
Eg. `ffi.load("./liblibrary.so")`.

I've read that `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` need to be set.
Eg:

```
export LUA_PATH="$PWD/src/?.lua"
export LUA_CPATH="$PWD/lib/?.so"
```

Setting `LUA_PATH` enables me to "require" lua files from other directories, but `LUA_CPATH` doesn't seem to help with loading shared objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffi.load` uses the normal `dlopen` mechanism of your operating system.

On Linux, this means that you need to add your libraries path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Once `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set, Lua is able to find the library.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589237/1591957) helped me debug my situation by printing any matching libraries on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

[Relevant FFI documentation](https://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html)

Comment: You're confusing two unrelated mechanisms of loading libraries: 1) `lua -l library` which is equivalent to `require"library"`; 2) `ffi.load()`.  The method #1 is used for Lua libraries which expose `luaopen_*()`, the method #2 - for arbitrary C libraries.  The method #1 depends on `LUA_CPATH`, the method #2 - on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but it doesn't explain why the above works.

Comment: Why do you think "the above works"?  You have not run your code.  Otherwise you would have noticed the typo `LB_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Dude. Chill. I'm sorry that my manual modification of the steps I took lead to a trivial typo. You can always edit an answer. I realised after I wrote that, that I'm just using `lua -l` as a diagnostic, but you're looking at it from the pov of "lua -l won't work there". I used it as a way to demonstrate that lua was able to progress to the next stage of finding the library. I was not expecting it to load it successfully. There are no search results for "ffi.load file not found". If diagnosing and resolving an issue using "incorrect" tools is wrong then I'm sorry.

Comment: Having the typo corrected, your answer is still wrong.  1) The question was about `ffi.load`, but the answer is about `lua -l` which is a completely different mechanism.  2) `lua -l` behavior does not depend on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (I have just checked that on my PC).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/adamlwgriffiths/5e78ae9efbd302918f95fe16a2189c10

Comment: In your gist `lua -l library` successfully finds `library.lua` and raises error while `ffi.load()`-ing .so file (`ffi.load` does depend on LD_LIBRARY_PATH).  But in your answer `lua -l library` shows error "module 'library' not found" which can not be fixed by LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Ok, that's making waaaaaay more sense. The combination of there being a lua file and a .so with the same name (sans the lib*) is why `lua -l` starts working. It is just loading the .lua file which then performs the `ffi.load`. It appeared that `lua -l` was going directly to the .so file, but it's not.

Comment: I've removed references to `lua -l`. Although it helped me debug my issue, it only occurred by way of the .lua file doing the `ffi.load` anyway. As you say, it's irrelevant.